# synchornous code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

The code is written in Angularjs in Ionic framework. I think people from Angular background can also answer this question.

When I call this function alert shows empty array "[]" and "undefined" respectively. I think this is happening cause of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. I want this function to execute synchronously.

```
 /*This is the constructor */
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public SP: SqliteProvider) {
 }
 /*my function*/
 getCustomerById()
 {
     this.SP.getCustomerById(this.id);
     this.customerById  = this.SP.customerById; 
        alert(this.SP.customerById);
        alert(this.SP.customerById[0]);

 }
```

/* The function in SqliteProvider */

```
 getCustomerById(cid)
{
    this.customerById = [];
    this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.dbName,
        location: 'default'
    })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{

            db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id= ?', [cid])
                .then(result => {

                        var json = JSON.parse(result.rows.item(0).json);
                        //alert(json);
                        this.customerById.push(json);
                       // alert(JSON.stringify(this.customerObject));
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: `I want this function to execute synchronously` <= **no, you don't.** You just do not know how to use asynchronous calls correctly. Read the above duplicate link's answer, specifically the heading named **ES2015+: Promises with then()** which is similar to what `sqllite.create` and `db.executeSql` return. You need to return a promise to your caller so the caller (getCustomerById) can subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code from the SqliteProvider method?
I am pretty sure it returns either a [Promise](https://javebratt.com/wtf-promise/) or an [Observable](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-observables-for-ionic-2/).

The thing with Promises and Observables are that the caller must wait until they have finished their job and then proceed, in a closure method.

So you should do something like the following:

```
this.SP.getCustomerById(this.id).then((customer) => {
    this.SP.customerById = customer;
    alert(this.SP.customerById);
}, error => {console.log(error)});
```

Note that in case your SqliteProvider method returns an **Observable** and not a **Promise**, you will have to change the code accordingly (add **subscribe** instead of **then**)

You can read an awesome tutorial for Promises [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2016/02/angular2-ionic2-data-services-promises-observables/) and for Observables [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-observables-for-ionic-2/).

**EDIT after posted method:**

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981818/4679732).
There is actually no need to have an inner customerById variable.
Actually it;s not a good practice, since your method should only retrieve the customer, not assigning it to a variable.
You should alter your code as following:

```
 getCustomerById(cid)
{
    return
    this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.dbName,
        location: 'default'
    })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{
            return
            db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id= ?', [cid])
                .then(result => {
                   return JSON.parse(result.rows.item(0).json);
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: I added the function in the description  @paul

Comment: See the edited answer